# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using the spring framework and when I try to register a user with postman I keep getting this error in the console, so I cannot register a user

```sh
POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: c8f92e31-e8f6-40d9-90b0-2bd4faba0552
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Request Body
{
    "username":"TestUserX",
    "email":"TestUserX@bla.com",
    "password":"password1"
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have written and the log generated by your Spring application when you make this request.

Comment: @Ferdinand, I guess your server is not running at 8080. Please verify whether the server is running or not.

Comment: @jrhamza how do i  verify?

Comment: @MeetK. Github link maybe, cause its a lot of code! https://github.com/ferdinandmwal123/SpringRedditClone

Comment: @Ferdinand, You can check in application.properties for the server.port. If not specified, please check the console for default port, while starting the application. I can see server port  in the eclipse console, while starting the application from eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing an @Entity annotation in my models and this was causing a failure in the server. Also, I hadn't properly mapped some variables.Turns out spring annotations are really important :)

Answer (score 1):

Api Port Number could also cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error could also be caused when your project isn't running.